WordPress installed in subfolder, link to achor link in homepage in menu
My staging site is installed automatically in a subfolder (at one.com).
I need a menu with a pointer to an anchor link in the homepage, and of course when I copy back the staging to production (which is at the root of the domain), the menu should still work...
Permalinks are set to "Post name".
When I am in a certain page, e.g. "test_page" (not the home page), and I make a Custom link in the menu to "home#Who_we_are", it does not work of course (as the system tries to resolve this to test_page/home#Who_we_are"...
then I try to put "/home#who_we_are" but this resolves (strangely enough) to the root domain and not to the staging folder... (but of course this works on the production site).
The general settings are pointing ok for the staging site (both WordPress Address URL and Site Address URL point to the subfolder where the staging area exists).
So what else could I try to make this work?
A solution by adding lines to the .htaccess file is not ok since this also is copied back from staging to production...
I think I tried about everything...
